# read stdout of ssh command execution

Tags: c, ssh

I use the following code to run process on another server using ssh.

```
ssh HOST "/Desktop/hello"
```

my ./hello program uses printf to print stuff.

I then use popen with fgets to read those loggings, but I'm not getting anything.

So I tried to run that ssh command on my terminal and the result is the same where I do not get any logging.

What could I do to see the logs?

Comment: Consider using a SSH library instead.

Comment: The point of your question seems to be that this "hello" program doesn't work. But you haven't told us anything about it. Where is it? Do you get any errors when you run it? Could you post the source code?

Answer (score 0):

You can run command like that:

> ssh HOST "/Desktop/hello" >> file.log

and then open this 'file.log' with another program to see logs from 'hello'

you can write simple code which just opens file descriptor and reads the file context or just

> tail -f file.log

EDIT:

try to use stderr instead of stdout and see if it works just like that:

> fprintf(stderr, "This is a printf %d\n", 345);

stderr never needs flush and may be useful for you

Comment: try to use stderr instead of stdout and see if it works just like that:
 fprintf(stderr, "This is a printf call %d\n", 1234); stderr never needs flush and may be useful for you